# Convert from java to scala

Tags: java, scala, r-tree

I am making an r-tree and I have some problem to convert from java to scala this line of code 
`private RTree<T>.Node chooseLeaf(RTree<T>.Node n, RTree<T>.Entry e)`
Whatever I try it ends up in error. Any suggestion to solve my problem will be welcome.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: We're going to need to see some more code. What do you have so far? What else have you tried? What errors are you getting ?

Comment: Hi @nik, welcome to **StackOverflow**, it is great that you have already tried to solve it!, If you could paste the code that you have tried, and a exact description of why it isn't working or a clear question of what you don't understand, it would be more easy to help you.

Comment: Can you show us your scala code that is erroring?

Answer (score 1):

A direct translation would be:

```
def chooseLeaf[T](RTree[T].Node n, RTree[T].Entry e): RTree[T].Node = {
  // ...
}
```

But if this method is in `RTree[T]` then it is simpler:

```
class RTree[T] {
   case class Node(...)
   case class Entry(...)

   def chooseLeaf(Node n, Entry e): Node = {
     // ...
   }
}
```